# How to add meta data for formControl?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

I have array of forms `FormGroup`;

```
let forms = [this.form1, this.form2];
```

Each form has several controls: `FormControl`.

How to add additional data to `FormControl` for example type of element (input, textarea, select)?

For example I have form:

```
export class ProfileEditorComponent {
  profileForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: [''],
    lastName: [''],
    address: this.fb.group({
      street: [''],
      city: [''],
      state: [''],
      zip: ['']
    }),
  });
```

How can I know that under zip field should be `input` or `select`?

How to iterate `profileForm` in template with nested form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answered before the edit of the question**

**UPDATE**

The following is called module augmentation as described <s>[here](https://alligator.io/typescript/module-augmentation/)</s> or [in the official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation)

This allows for augmenting (e.g. adding methods pr properties) classes from third party modules

**ORIGINAL**

We had the requirement to have a warning validators which is not provided by angular.
What we did was the following in our `typings.d.ts` file which has to reside in our applications root directory.

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

declare module '@angular/forms' {

  export interface AbstractControl {
    warnings: ValidationErrors | null;
  }
}

AbstractControl.prototype.warnings = ''; //add a default value instead of ''
```

`ValidationErrors` is a custom class of ours.

You could do something like

```
declare module '@angular/forms' {

  export interface AbstractControl {
    elementType: string; // input, textarea, select
  }
}
```

With that you all your `AbstractControls` in your application would have the property `elementType` available.

You could also use `FormControl` instead of `AbstractControl`

Comment: Could you provide a sample? How to appy this to exist form?

Comment: you wouldn't apply this directly to your form.
Every `FormControl` in your application would automatically have this newly defined property `elementType`

Comment: It seems just copying your code and adding meta fields to abstract/formcontrol actually makes other things like Validators and FormBuilder no longer exists in @angular/forms. Do I need to just create a blank interface for any class i plan on using from angular forms to get this to work?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't provide an answer for that. I haven't worked with angular for 2 years now. If I remember correctly the code above was all we needed.
Look here for example -> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation

Comment: Thanks for the reference @Arikael. All I needed was the prototype stuff and i was good. I also slightly edited the answer to reflect so others don't run into this

Answer (score 0):

There's a open issue that is proposing this feature: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19686.

For now, you can apply a not so "beautiful" solution. You can transform a `FormControl` in a `FormGroup`, and create a `FormControl` or `FormGroup` with metadata:

```js
this.fb.group({
  firstName: this.fb.group({
    value: [''],
    _metadata: this.fb.group({
      type: ['input'], // type of element
    })
  })
)}
```